# How can I change an image file based on the current date?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a solution for this: I would like my site's background to change automatically, each month. Is there coding that will check against a calendar to select from an array of 12 different image files that are present in the program?

(January is image1.png, February is image2.png etc...)

I believe this is to be a Javascript solve, but if there are any other solves, I would appreciate them. I haven't found a workable solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current month in JavaScript using the built-in Date object.

```js
let d = new Date();
let currentMonth = d.getMonth();
console.log(currentMonth);
```

Then you can save the name of the images in an array and access the index using the number from the *currentMonth* variable

```js
    let d = new Date();
    let currentMonth = d.getMonth();

    let imageNames = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png", "image5.png", "image6.png"];

    imageNames[currentMonth];
```

Comment: YES! Thank you Ahsan! So, from there, I can attach variables to the image files, and use if gates to change the `<image>`, correct?

Comment: you can also do it without using if statements.

`let imageNames = ["image1.png", "image2.png" .....]`.

using the value from currentMonth just do `imageNames[currentMonth]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try like below

```
const imagesByMonth = [
    {
        month: 'JAN',
        image: 'jan image'
    },
    {
        month: 'FEB',
        image: 'feb image'
    },
    {
        month: 'MAR',
        image: 'mar image'
    },
    {
        month: 'APR',
        image: 'apr image'
    },
    {
        month: 'MAY',
        image: 'may image'
    },
    {
        month: 'JUN',
        image: 'june image'
    }
];

const getMonth = new Date().getMonth();

console.log('imageToDisplay', imagesByMonth[getMonth].image); // "june image"
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you Goutham *edit* You made a more straight forward solve than I was anticipating! Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Once the DOM content has loaded, set the background image to be an element of the `backgroundImages` array, based off of the 0 indexed month achieved from `(new Date()).getMonth()`;

```js
const backgroundImages = [
  "https://i.imgur.com/R8se5g1b.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/1EsqT0Fb.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/JXetxQhb.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/s3sPQTYb.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/JhLkIZHb.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/zfmhZ27b.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/1SSVsBHb.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/8pTwPlXb.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/SazaHUqb.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/6VP86jlb.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/BnPdUHKb.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/ydi5jMhb.jpg",
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${backgroundImages[(new Date()).getMonth()]})`)
```

Note: these images are small so they repeat. You'll want full-sized images for backgrounds, and you can also change how they're displayed with css